# RoR: Nested Form , Hidden Field, value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have a Huge Nested Form, where it has a TASK and an field_for tsk1, tsk2 and tsk3, which all them belongs to TASK, but i'd like to tsk2 to get the id of the tsk1 and tsk3 of the tsk2, how can i handle this? i have tried hidden fields with value => [:tsk1_id] but didn't worked.

_form = http://pastebin.com/K8qS9Tqw

task controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    @task = Task.new
    @tasks = Task.all
  end


  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to projetopo_path, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Task was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit( :projeto_id, :raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo,  :tsk1s_attributes => [ :raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo, :_destroy, :task_id, :tsk2s_attributes => [:tsk1_id]], :tsk2s_attributes => [ :raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo, :task_id, :tsk1_id ,:_destroy, :tsk3s_attributes => [:tsk2_id]], :tsk3s_attributes => [ :raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo, :tsk2_id, :_destroy, :task_id])
end
end
```

task model

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tsk1s
has_many :tsk2s 
has_many :tsk3s
has_many :projetos
belongs_to :projeto

accepts_nested_attributes_for :tsk1s, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tsk2s, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tsk3s, allow_destroy: true

end
```

tsk1 model

```
class Tsk1 < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :task
has_many :tsk2s, through: :task
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tsk2s, allow_destroy: true



end
```

tsk2 model

```
class Tsk2 < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :tsk1
has_many :tsk3s , through: :tsk1
belongs_to :task

accepts_nested_attributes_for :tsk3s, allow_destroy: true

end
```

tsk3 model

```
class Tsk3 < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :tsk2
belongs_to :task

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are not assigned until you `save` the records, so there's no way the form can submit something like `tsk1_id` - it doesn't exist yet.

What you'll need to do is add the wiring in your controller to attach `tsk2` to `tsk1` and `tsk3` to `tsk2`.

```
@task = Task.new(task_params)
@task.tsk1s.first.tsk2 = @task.tsk2s.first
@task.tsk2s.first.tsk3 = @task.tsk3s.first
@task.save
```

---

Part of the trouble might be that this is a strange schema. You're accessing some tskNs `through: :task` and others directly, which makes the wiring complicated.

You might consider removing `Tsk1`, `Tsk2`, and `Tsk3` in favor of:

1. Just a `Task` with an optional `parent_id`. Then you can build any tree of tasks and dependencies and get some functionality out of gems like [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree).
2. `Task` and `Subtask`, with an `order` attribute on `Subtask`. Then you can assign `Subtask`s to `Task`s and specify the `order` they need to be finished in.

Rails' form helpers will handle these cases much better than your current version.

Comment: IF i do remove tsk1s... can it still work to add more fields like fields_for do? There are any working example that you can send me?

Comment: You can use `fields_for` on any associated model. Check out https://gorails.com/episodes/forum-nested-attributes-and-fields-for for a recent, simple demo.

Comment: if i use this commad of yours, it will work? Where do i put then, def a new method?

Comment: Yes, i did what you said so, but it didn't worked, maybe i did it wrong, could you please explain to me like i'm five?

Comment: Not in this space, but there is already lots of help out there: [Form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), [Complex Rails forms with nested attributes](http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/) (a little old), [Nested forms and a many to many association](http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/), [Advanced forms](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/advanced-forms).

Answer (score 0):

It's very complicated underestand what you want because in your relationchips are ambiguity references

```ruby
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tsk1s
  has_many :tsk2s, through: tsk1s
  has_many :tsk3s, through: tsk2s
  has_many :projetos
  belongs_to :projeto

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tsk1s, allow_destroy: true
end
```

```ruby
class Tsk1 < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :task
has_many :tsk2s
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tsk2s, allow_destroy: true

end
```

```ruby
class Tsk2 < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :tsk1
has_many :tsk3s

accepts_nested_attributes_for :tsk3s, allow_destroy: true

end
```

You have to modify the params to accept the above modification (I assume that you can fix this)

```
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit( :projeto_id, :raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo,
   :tsk1s_attributes => [ :raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo, :_destroy, :task_id, 
   :tsk2s_attributes => [:tsk1_id]], :tsk2s_attributes => [ :raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo, :task_id, :tsk1_id ,:_destroy, :tsk3s_attributes => [:tsk2_id]],  
   :tsk3s_attributes => [ :raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo, :tsk2_id, :_destroy, :task_id])
end
```

In your view

```
   ### inputs for task ####
<%= f.fields_for :tsk1s do |tsk1| %>
   ### inputs for tsk1 ####
 <%= tsk1.fields_for :tsk2s do |tsk2| %>
      ### inputs for tsk2 ####
 <%= tsk2.fields_for :tsk3s do |tsk3| %>
      ### inputs for tsk3 ####
```

Comment: being simple, i have a project, where it has tasks, and tasks do child-tasks, im using nested form to be able to add any amount of tasks, that's why there are 3 tables named tsk1, tsk2 and tsk3. I have made what you said and got an error: undefined local variable or method `tsk1' for #<#<Class:0x007fdbce80d908>:0x007fdbce81b5f8> , If you can name me other way to accomplish want i need it'd be wonderful.. thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know what happened with your form. Theoretically this should works. Please debug the object tsk1 in your form. Search by betterError for improve your debugs